# Single Thicker vertical lines both side of the text

Tags: fonts, vertical-alignment, text

I want vertical lines both sides of the text (please see attached image). The lines should increase according to number of rows. Please note this is not in the table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this can meet your expectations:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newmdenv[topline=false, leftline=true, rightline=true, bottomline=false,%
  linewidth=2pt, innerleftmargin=12pt, rightmargin=-4pt,%
  innerrightmargin=12pt, skipabove=8pt, skipbelow=8pt]{leftrightbar}%

\begin{document}

\begin{leftrightbar}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{leftrightbar}

\end{document}
```

[image]